# how to get UIAlertView otherButtons' title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertVw clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d 。", buttonIndex];
    UIAlertView *newAlertVw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INFO" message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [newAlertVw show];
}


UIAlertView *alertVw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE"
                                                      message:@"box message"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"hide"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"T1", @"T2", nil];
    [alertVw show];
```

if user touched the one of otherButtons, yes, we know which button that user touched.
then, how can I to get the title of button that user just touched?
thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UIAlertView`? It shows a method for getting the button titles.

Comment: sorry, next time before i post a question, i will check docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the delegate on your `UIAlertView` set to `self` you can use this:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView didDismissWithButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSLog(@"Button Title -----> %@",[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);

  // or you can check if it equals to string
  if([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]isEqual:@"Enter"])
  {
    // your code goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is `buttonTitleAtIndex:` and the info is simply found on the UIAlertView doc page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/buttonTitleAtIndex:

I advise you to refer to the doc as often as you can this is how you will learn and remember.

Comment: You should close this post by setting it sovled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to use the delegate method you have to use `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`.

**and not**

> -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView didDismissWithButton **At** Index:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:

I guess it was just a typo of Pancho.